# Having a type for options encoded as strings in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I don't know exactly what I'm looking for, so I apologize if the title is too generic.

There's a pattern I developed when I was coding in JavaScript where when a variable could only take one of n possible values, I would define an object like this:

```
const REQUEST_STATUS = {
  PENDING: "pending",
  SUCCESS: "success",
  FAILED: "failed"
}
```

and then later in the code I would avoid hardcoding one of those values by writing

```
const requestStatus = REQUEST_STATUS.PENDING
```

This has the advantage that in my IDE, if I hover over `REQUEST_STATUS.PENDING`, I actually see the object and the other possible values of the option.

I recently started working on a Typescript codebase where they are using union types:

```
type RequestStatus = "pending" | "success" | "failed"
```

and this has the disadvantage that a lot of times, logic is performed on variables that are not type-annotated (yeah, yay me) and my IDE labels the types as `any`, so I really have nowhere to start. I want to avoid hardcoding strings when performing logic with variables with such type. Is there any nice way to preserve the advantages of my vanilla JavaScript technique within Typescript in a 'Typescripty' way? Basically I need two features:

- I can encode the type that coresponds to one of n possible values, usually strings
- I can refer to one or more of the values by referring them to the type, not just as mere strings.

Comment: typescript has [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) for this purpose, which I think is just the terminology you're missing.

Comment: @chrisbajorin: I explored a bit after posting my question and I think what I want is along the lines of `enum Example { option1, option2, option3 }` followed by `type ExampleType = keyof typeof Example` since it makes ExampleType the union type `"option1" | "option2" | "option3"`. I might answer my own question if I settle for this option.

Comment: if you use a string enum, it acts as both the type and the union value: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/KYOwrgtgBASgogRQKpwMoBUD6GCC6mpQDeAUFFAApwByAIgJLUDiUAvFAEQAOoAJgJYgA5hwA0ZKKiQBhaWkLsOAZzABjVcCVKxEgGI56AGTi02nAGYBDfgBtgvDiQC+JEubAhVAF34B7EFBelgDWmgBqlgBO-JYgXgAUAG5RMXEAXLCIKBjY6HgEAJTELkGhShHRsQnwyGhYuPioAHT6RiYFANwkQA)

Comment: @chrisbajorin : Why can't I see the possible values of the enum when I hover over the enum as a type in VSCode? If I write something like `enum Letters { a, b }` and write later `const exampleLetter: Letters = Letters.a`, if I hover over `Letters`, all I see is `enum Letters`, that's not very helpful. Whereas if I replace this by `type LettersType = keyof typeof Letters` and  `const exampleLetter: LettersType = Letters.a`, by hovering I get `type LettersType = "a" | "b"`, which gives me the information I want. If I use a JSDoc I can get the values to be listed, but that's a lot more to write.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the point. You want the a namespaced union (an enum), so I would think that you would be importing that object when you need it rather than caring about the string literal (the hovering). Getting both adds verbosity that seems useless (to me): [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gSzAExgXhgbwFAxgQQC4YAiAQxIBpcYAhYkgIxOwF8YyIZRIoBubFACeABwCmMAGpkANgFcxEADwAVAHzoYKgNoBrMUJAAzLQF0Bw8fCSoM0+YqWWxx6yjUCjcsMCgJwMFBk+hAAwuDQABS6xIgoAJRYrILBiuG8kXHIAHT48RapYRFQkeQk+TAA9JWBABYIXBBiYgC2XCIgSFAyilxQIDAtYpQwEEjAEoZyMLVkAG4SAAZZixxzZAgyZIw9QA)

Comment: @chrisbajorin The thing you commented that it seemed pointless also seems pointless to me, but if you hover over the object you want to see the possible values it can take, no? I see that you did something different which was declaring a constant object 'as const' (I still don't know what 'as const' does...) but with an Enum, on the line where you wrote `takesConst(Kind.A);`, if I hover over `Kind` and want to know what are the other options, I see `enum Kind` which is not very enlightening if the enum was defined in some other module.

Comment: `as const` is a "const assertion". On objects, it converts properties to `readonly` and narrows the property types to their literal value: e.g. `Kind.A` becomes `"a"` instead of `string`. The problem I see from a maintenance standpoint is that you have a value and a type that are only related through developer awareness. The value `Kind` and the type `Kind` can drift if someone makes a typo, while enums always occupy both the type and value space. seeing `enum Kind` indicates to the consumer that they need to import that value/type, which is usually contextually linked to functions that use it

Comment: @chrisbajorin: I settled for using string enums and using JSDoc to document the values that the enum takes. This has the double pro that my values are explained somewhere and I see them when I hover on the enum because JSDoc displays the different values. I was sort of reluctant to this type approach with `keyof typeof` precisely because of what you mentioned; it's hard to consistently keep the type and its values aligned without some sort of construct, and I figured out enum is the construct, I just have to figure out a way to make VSCode work for me on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I settled for using string enums in this way:

```
/**
 * @enum REQUEST_STATUS
 * @property pending - Status used when the API call is on going
 * @property success - Status used when the API call is settled successfully
 * @property failed - Status used when the API call is settled unsuccessfully
 */
enum REQUEST_STATUS {
  PENDING = "pending",
  SUCCESS = "success",
  FAILED = "failed"
}
```

Since enums are a type in themselves, there was no actual need for me to convert the enum into a union type; enums do that well already when it comes to logic. All I was interested in was being able to hover over my enum when being used in some other scripts to see what values it can take. The JSDoc is something I wanted to use anyway, and this way I can document the values as well. So this sounds like the way to go for me.

Comment: I didn't know enums are their own type, so I definitely learned something! Thank you chrisbajorin and Andri Nic for the enlightening discussion.

Comment: also usually when using enums, there is no need to specify if they are strings , just like defining something like this `enum REQUEST_STATUS {
  PENDING,
  SUCCESS,
  FAILED
}`

Comment: @AndriNic : Thanks for letting me know :) specifying the strings is still useful in some cases however, so it's good enums can do both!

Answer (score 1):

what about doing like this:

```
enum REQUEST_STATUS {
  PENDING = "pending",
  SUCCESS = "success",
  FAILED = "failed"
}

type RequestStatus = REQUEST_STATUS.PENDING | REQUEST_STATUS.SUCCESS |REQUEST_STATUS.FAILED,
```

but i think doing  `type RequestStatus = REQUEST_STATUS` , if you need all.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that's what I'm looking for! I didn't know enums. Is there anyway I don't have to write out all the values for the type? Something like "unionof" Object.values(REQUEST_STATUS)... also is there any difference for my use-case between an enum and a simple object? Because if I define a union type like that, a good old object could do the same job no?

Comment: if you do `type RequestStatus = REQUEST_STATUS` is like making an union